# js - Stop after 1 hour

Tags: javascript, gettime

I was creating a program which should stop automatically a `<b>`. So please tell me how, here is a little bit I am thinking off:

```
var time = date.getTime();
var seconds = 0;
if (time + seconds == date.getTime())
{
// Stop everything i do by myself :)
}
```

Comment: use a `setTimeout`.

Comment: Yes but i dont want to use this ;)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
var keepGoing = true;


setTimeout(function(){

    keepGoing = false;

}, 1000 * 60 * 60); //one hour


while(keepGoing){

    //stuff to do

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to accomplish this.

```js
function doStuff(){
    //do whatever you need to do
}

var is_running = true;

setTimeout(function(){
    is_running = false; //Stop the program
}, 1000 * 60 * 60); //Do this after 1 hour

while(is_running){
    doStuff(); //whatever your function does
}
```